# How to remove table border completely from an HTML page

Tags: css, html

I am trying to remove table border completely for table id="t01" (if possible in a way supported by HTML5 as well) and have tried following options but none have removed the border so far.

```
In css:
    border: 0;
    border-collapse:collapse;
    border: none !important;
    border-spacing: 0;
    border-padding: 0;
In table tag:
    <table id="t01", border="0", cellspacing="0", cellpadding="0">
```

I think I am missing to set some table property/attribute and so it's default value is being used and the border stays as it is.

Can you please suggest me what other options I can try to make the table border disappear completely?

Following is my HTML and as this will be a single web page, I am not using a seperate css file.

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Dashboard</title>
<style>
span.note1 {float:left}
span.note2 {font-size:80%}
table#t01, th, td {     
    width:300px;
    font-size:80%;
    border-spacing: 0;
    border-padding: 0;
    border: none;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
table#t02, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width:300px;
    font-size:80%;  
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div style="float:left; width:50%; background-color:AliceBlue">
<b>Call Volume Tab Configuration</b>
<table id="t01", border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <caption><span class="note1">Customize your personal view of the Call Volume Tab.</span></caption>
  <tr>
    <td><form><input type="checkbox" name="trunk_usage" value="1">% Trunk Usage</form></td>
    <td><form><input type="checkbox" name="pre_ivr" value="1">Pre-IVR Call Volume</form></td>    
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><form><input type="checkbox" name="trunk_group" value="1">Trunk Group Utilization</form></td>
    <td><form><input type="checkbox" name="average_speed" value="1">Average Speed of Answer</form></td>    
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><form><input type="checkbox" name="outage_call" value="1">Outage Call Volume</form></td>
    <td><form><input type="checkbox" name="ivr_call" value="1">IVR Call Volume</form></td>    
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><form><input type="checkbox" name="non_outage_call" value="1">Non-Outage Call Volume</form></td>
    <td><form><input type="checkbox" name="post_ivr" value="1">Post-IVR Call Volume</form></td>    
  </tr>
</table>
<br /><span class="note2">Customize your personal thresholds that trigger alerts on the Call Volume Tab.</span>
</div>

<div style="float:left; width:50%; background-color:LightCyan">
<table id="t02", align="center">
  <caption>Call Volume Suppressed Alert History</caption>
  <tr style="background-color:SkyBlue">
    <th>AlertID</th>
    <th>Alert Action</th>       
    <th>UserID</th>
    <th>Time</th>
    <th>Comments</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>10334</td>
    <td>Suppress</td>       
    <td>JSmith</td>
    <th>12:25:03 PM</th>
    <th>ticket #11111</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>10225</td>
    <td>Suppress</td>       
    <td>JWilson</td>
    <th>12:25:03 PM</th>
    <th>ticket #11111</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>10558</td>
    <td>Suppress</td>       
    <td>JSmith</td>
    <th>12:25:03 PM</th>
    <th>ticket #11111</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>10559</td>
    <td>Suppress</td>       
    <td>JSmith</td>
    <th>12:25:03 PM</th>
    <th>ticket #11111</th>
  </tr>
</table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Just remove table#t02, th, td {  border: 1px solid black; } and there will be no border.. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because of the "Cascade" part of CSS, you are overriding your own "no border!" styles with styles that add a border back in.  The commas you are using between selectors in your CSS 
table#t01, th, td { ... }
table#t02, th, td { ... }
mean that the following styles are applied to ALL th, td, not just ones that are in table#01 or table#02

ALso, you do not need to add in "table" before "#01" and "#02" - you are using IDs for the tables - you don't need to be more specific and say that the selector apples to all Tables that have an ID of #01/#02.

The following CSS will clean things up for you. Also, you are applying "font-size: 80%" twice in your tables (through the table and through the td styles). You may want to reevaluate your math so you don't have to set that twice.

```
span.note1 {float:left}
span.note2 {font-size:80%}

table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width:300px;
    font-size:80%;     
}

th, td {
    font-size: 80%;
}

#t02, #t02 th, #t02 td {
    border: 1px solid black; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The th and td styles in the declaration for your second table are overwriting those in the first.  Change your selectors like this:

```
#t01, #t01 th, #t01 td {     
width:300px;
font-size:80%;
border-spacing: 0;
border-padding: 0;
border: none;
border-collapse: collapse;
}
#t02, #t02 th, #t02 td {
border: 1px solid black;
border-collapse: collapse;
width:300px;
font-size:80%;  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you've used the wrong markup for your css. Instead of `table#t01, th, td` you want to use `table#t01, #t01 th, #t01 td` as in the `th` of `#t01` and the `td` of `#t01` rather than your borders for all `th` and `td` being overwritten on your next css `table#t02, th, td`

Answer (score 1):

This CSS will work ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/miparnisari/1vvatn99/)). You just need to target elements more specifically.

```
#t01, #t01 td {
    width: 300px;
    font-size: 80%;
    border: 0;
}
#t02, #t02 th, #t02 td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 300px;
    font-size: 80%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

add this

```
table#t01{border:none}
```

Comment: Thank you all. I am too happy that I got so many responses in such a short time. 

I corrected the problem by specifying the #t01 and #t02 appropriately for both tables th and td.

I wish I had someone like you in my team to do peer review :-)

Answer (score 1):

You have removed the border in the first selection but again added in the second selection by targeting the `td` and `th` of whole page but not the `td` and `th` of second table, in the second selection you should target the `td` and `th` of the 2nd table, just see the following code snippet how I have removed the border. :-)

```css
span.note1 {float:left}
span.note2 {font-size:80%}
table#t01, th, td {     
    width:300px;
    font-size:80%;
    border-spacing: 0;
    border-padding: 0;
    border: none;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
table#t02, #t02 th, #t02 td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width:300px;
    font-size:80%;  
}
```

```html
<div style="float:left; width:50%; background-color:AliceBlue">
<b>Call Volume Tab Configuration</b>
<table id="t01", border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <caption><span class="note1">Customize your personal view of the Call Volume Tab.</span></caption>
  <tr>
    <td><form><input type="checkbox" name="trunk_usage" value="1">% Trunk Usage</form></td>
    <td><form><input type="checkbox" name="pre_ivr" value="1">Pre-IVR Call Volume</form></td>    
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><form><input type="checkbox" name="trunk_group" value="1">Trunk Group Utilization</form></td>
    <td><form><input type="checkbox" name="average_speed" value="1">Average Speed of Answer</form></td>    
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><form><input type="checkbox" name="outage_call" value="1">Outage Call Volume</form></td>
    <td><form><input type="checkbox" name="ivr_call" value="1">IVR Call Volume</form></td>    
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><form><input type="checkbox" name="non_outage_call" value="1">Non-Outage Call Volume</form></td>
    <td><form><input type="checkbox" name="post_ivr" value="1">Post-IVR Call Volume</form></td>    
  </tr>
</table>
<br /><span class="note2">Customize your personal thresholds that trigger alerts on the Call Volume Tab.</span>
</div>

<div style="float:left; width:50%; background-color:LightCyan">
<table id="t02", align="center">
  <caption>Call Volume Suppressed Alert History</caption>
  <tr style="background-color:SkyBlue">
    <th>AlertID</th>
    <th>Alert Action</th>       
    <th>UserID</th>
    <th>Time</th>
    <th>Comments</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>10334</td>
    <td>Suppress</td>       
    <td>JSmith</td>
    <th>12:25:03 PM</th>
    <th>ticket #11111</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>10225</td>
    <td>Suppress</td>       
    <td>JWilson</td>
    <th>12:25:03 PM</th>
    <th>ticket #11111</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>10558</td>
    <td>Suppress</td>       
    <td>JSmith</td>
    <th>12:25:03 PM</th>
    <th>ticket #11111</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>10559</td>
    <td>Suppress</td>       
    <td>JSmith</td>
    <th>12:25:03 PM</th>
    <th>ticket #11111</th>
  </tr>
</table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This css should work-

```
 table#t01, th, td {     
  width:300px;
  font-size:80%;
  border-spacing: 0;
  border-padding: 0;
  border: none;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  }
  table#t02, #t02 th, #t02 td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width:300px;
  font-size:80%;  
  }
```